# entity framework repository and async call

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-6

I have a repository that use EF to access to the database. This repository is used for my principal application.

My quiestion is if it is a good idea to call the methods of my repository in async way, or is better a normal call.

If is a good idea the async way. is it good idea to call async to my repository methods or is there any other way to use EF in async way?

Thanks.
Daimroc.

Comment: What would be the goal of calling it asynchronously? Note that EF5 does not support async and EF in general (especially ObjectContext and ObjectStateManager) is not thread safe. EF6 has support for asynchrony but note that the goal of async is not to emulate multi threading but to save resources and therefore you should not send a query to the database while the previous query is not completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async support in regards to EF and server-side programming is mainly to help your site scale better on the server. By releasing the thread while operations that might take a while (such as accessing the database) the thread will be available to another web request. Once the database returns with a result you can continue from where you left off.

As Pawel stated in the comment above: An instance of the ObjectContext is not meant to be used in multithreaded environments. Create an instance for each request that you process.

To answer your original question: Yes, it is a good idead to use the new async support in EF6 if you are worried about scaling your site.